# ACT as a linking verb?

Tags: linking-verbs

I came across a diagrammed sentence in a Houghton Mifflin English (Level 10, Pub. date 1992) book where the verb ***act*** was implied to be a linking verb. To simplify, the sentence in essence said, "He acts proud." ***Proud*** was diagrammed as a predicate adjective (and, in fact, most dictionaries will say that ***proud*** is an adjective, and not also an adverb).

So, the diagram showed ***act*** as a linking verb with ***proud*** as the predicate adjective.

I balked at that, thinking that ***act*** is an action verb; however, to use ***proudly*** does not quite sound right: *He acts proudly.*

Assuming act is indeed a linking verb, would someone please help me understand how ***act*** might indeed be a linking verb in this case--even though when I think of ***act***, I think of literal action, not linking.

Comment: I think Tim has it right. You could also have a predicate noun, as in "He acts the fool all the time" with the sense that he always has the demeanour of a fool.

Answer (score 2):

He behaves in a manner that "says" he is proud.

**Acts** is *roughly* synonymous with **seems**.  I hedge there because their complements are different.

He seems proud.

He seems to be proud.

He acts proud.

<sup>not OK</sup> He acts to be proud.

He appears to be proud.

He appears proud.

Comment: Whether we want to admit it to the grammar book or not, in some constructions it certainly **acts** as if it were a linking verb.  Consider "Act surprised when Aunt Fern gives you knitted mittens."